# How to install Gmail apk on ADT emulator?

Tags: android, email, gmail, apk, mailing

I'm working on an email app for Android, and I'd like to install the Gmail apk on my emulator in order to test it.

How can I do that?

I have seen tutorials on how to do it on windows, but I'm working with Linux.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your question here : http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi try this tutorial they have given a step by step procedure how to install emulator and apps in it on Linux **[click here][1]**


  [1]: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Run-Android-Applications-on-Ubuntu-115152.shtml

Comment: Selvin: I've followed the steps you mentioned in that link, but the "./adb pull /system/build.prop" command didn't work!
Intrepidd: I did share on that!
androidgeek: Thanks for the tuto but it's for the old version, and I want the new one.